# Issue in defining a bean of type

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, annotations

I tried to Create Interface by extending the CRUD Repository with annotation @Repository. Also I tried to use the interface function in Service class using Auto wired annotation. But I am facing the issue given below

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field bookRepository in com.example.service.BookService required a bean of type 'com.example.repo.BookRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.repo.BookRepository' in your configuration.
```

Project Structure are given below:

[image]

Comment: Include _code_, but just glancing at your project structure you don't seem to have your main class in a package that contains your repository, and it doesn't look like you have `@EnableJpaRepositories`. (`@Repository` is not needed, but Spring Data scanning is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your project structure. Try replacing all other packages under:

```
com.example.learn
```

package

Folowing above you won't need @ComponentScan and @Repository as @SpringBootApplication will take care of it.